# Leftovers after uninstallation of software in windows

Tags: windows, windows-registry, uninstall

What is the process of knowing the leftover files and registry entries after the uninstallation of a software in Windows?

Comment: I search the hard drive for folders related to the software name or names, registry can be tricky sometimes as they can put the keys under any name they wish but usually reflect the folder names you find.

Comment: There are some 3rd party uninstaller software's the do a good job of uninstalling the software and finding leftovers and removing them from the file system and registry. Revo is one that comes to mind...http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

Answer (score 3):

The only way of knowing all that is to log all the changes the installer does to the system and then, when the program is being uninstalled, undo all those changes according to this log. All else is just guessing.

This is, actually, the method the uninstaller for every program works, at least in theory - there is a list of folders/files/registry-entries that uninstaller removes when executed. Practice, of course, is far from that. For very many reasons.

@Moab suggested Revo, I'm using Wise Program Uninstaller.